# Without root access - how to enable PHP SQlite where PHP has been complied with "without-sqlite"?

Tags: php, sqlite, shared-hosting

I'm on a shared hosting environment where for some reason PHP has been complied with SQlite disabled. The host is unwilling to make any changes to the set-up. I'm stuck with the host for other reasons, unfortunately. There is also no PDO or MySQL support complied in.

Is there any way to enable SQlite (or another database solution) without root access? I have non-root SSH access.

Alternatively is there any library that allows database-like functionality using flat files?

Many thanks,

Jack

Comment: Just reading about dl(). Does anyone know where I can download "sqlite.so" so that I can try out the dl() technique?

Comment: i doubt it would work on a shared hosting, think of the security issues..

Comment: here i put it for php5.2.6 , 20060613 http://5element.pl/_/sqlite.so

Comment: You have got no SQLLite, no MySQL, and they won't add it. Time to get a new host.

Comment: maybe he can have MySQL but its expensive ? there are many hosts that provide cheap php hosting but expensive sqls... i know i transferred from one (to a dedic thank god) not long ago. but if the php hosting is good and cheap and you dont need a big, fast db, why change ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.c-worker.ch/txtdbapi/index_eng.php flat file SQL storage

---

http://pecl.php.net/package/SQLite

---

http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=SqliteWrappers

> ### PHP
>
> SQLite is bundled with PHP 5. http://www.php.net
>
> PHP 4 extension for SQLite. (Official) http://pecl.php.net/package/SQLite
>
> PEAR DB contains an interface for SQLite. http://pear.php.net/package/DB
>
> PHP driver for SQLite 3.XX (Unofficial). Also includes a PEAR DB driver class http://php-sqlite3.sourceforge.net
>
> PHP driver for SQLite. (Unofficial) http://freshmeat.net/projects/sqlite-php (no longer being worked on; see above)
>
> ADOdb database abstraction layer for PHP 4/5 is supporting SQLite. http://adodb.sourceforge.net/
>
> Creole - Common Database API for ZE2 supports SQLite. http://creole.phpdb.org/
>
> [SQLiteDB:](http://code.jenseng.com/db/) A simple wrapper class that supports ALTER TABLE statements.
>
> [PHP Hosting Tutorials:](http://blog.webhosting.uk.com/category/php-hosting-tutorials/)

Comment: Thanks for those links. Unfortunately as far as I can see most of those either assume that (a) you already have SQlite installed, and just provide abstractions layers and whatnot, or (b) you have root access to actually install SQlite.  

I wonder if some class exists that will take PDO update, selects etc, but store the result in a flat file - without any need to install/compile extra software?

Comment: i think no one made a SQlite for php (it would duplicate the built in) ... maybe just dont use sqlite but some other file based db

Comment: Yes, I'll have a Google for alternatives. It's just for a proof-of-concept to convince of the need for a full MySQL DB install, so it doesn't need to be fast or ACID compliant or anything. Thanks.

Comment: Your latest EDIT looks like it'll do the job nicely, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are a fair few flat-file-databases supported by PHP (assuming that they're compiled in) - you'll want to use the [DBA abstraction](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dba.php) functions. The list of supported databases can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/dba.requirements.php).

Comment: Thanks. Those looked promising, but the host seems to have complied WIHOUT all of those - very thorough! The best I have found for standalone classes is here: http://lukeplant.me.uk/resources/flatfile